# How to get the quotient and remainder effectively without using "/" and "%"?

Tags: algorithm, math, go

I have implemented a simple function which returns the quotient and remainder when the divisor is the power of `10`:

```
func getQuotientAndRemainder(num int64, digits uint) (int64, int64) {
    divisor := int64(math.Pow(10, float64(digits)))
    if num >= divisor {
        return num / divisor, num % divisor
    } else {
        return 0, num
    }
}
```

Just curious, except using directly `/` and `%` operators, is there any better algorithm to get the the quotient and remainder? Or only in the case when the divisor is the power of `10`?

Comment: I can't answer directly as it relates to the go language and I've never used it or looked deeply enough into how it does things to say anything authoritative.  I will say these are operations normally implemented in hardware.  In fact, on x86 hardware, I believe the division and modulus operations are computed together, so once you get one, you get the other for "free" so to speak.  So I think you're going to be hard pressed to find a "better" implementation except for some pretty esoteric uses of the word "better".

Comment: @andand: division by a constant is slightly cheaper than modulo by a constant.  If the `div` instruction is needed (instead of multiply by a magic constant and shift), then yes, you get quotient and remainder at once.  Any decent compiler will use both results from the same instruction, instead of running it twice.

Comment: @Nan: if there was a cheaper way to do `/` or `%`, compilers would use it to implement `/` and `%`.  (When the divisor is a compile-time constant, compilers can do cool tricks).  Is there any kind of restriction, like positive integers only?  If so, knowing that can help a compiler do better.

Answer (score 1):

```
return num / divisor, num % divisor
```

The "algorithm" is sound and written in arguably the best way possible: expressively. If anything, this part of your code may be overly complicated:

```
int64(math.Pow(10, float64(digits)))
```

Converting to and from  `float64` is arguably sub-optimal. Also, 10 to the power of anything greater than 18 will overflow `int64`. I suggest you add a sanity check and replace the code with a multiplying loop and measure its performance.

But then: if performance is your concern, just implement it in assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you should run some Go benchmarks: [Benchmarks, Package testing](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/).

Your solution doesn't look very efficient. Try this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func pow(base, exp int64) int64 {
    p := int64(1)
    for exp > 0 {
        if exp&1 != 0 {
            p *= base
        }
        exp >>= 1
        base *= base
    }
    return p
}

func divPow(n, base, exp int64) (q int64, r int64) {
    p := pow(base, exp)
    q = n / p
    r = n - q*p
    return q, r
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(divPow(42, 10, 1))
    fmt.Println(divPow(-42, 10, 1))
}
```

Output:

```
4 2
-4 -2
```

Benchmark:

```
BenchmarkDivPow                     20000000            77.4 ns/op
BenchmarkGetQuotientAndRemainder     5000000           296 ns/op
```